# IE10 and Modal Popup Extender always visible

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-10, modalpopupextender

It seems that my Modal Popup Extenders are always visible when using IE10.

```
<ajx:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpeNewTest" 
    PopupControlID="pnlTest" TargetControlID="btnNew"
    DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTest" 
    CssClass="ModalWindow" ScrollBars="Auto">
<!--Stuff here -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Is there something that is missing? I've looked online and no one seems to have this problem.

The CSS is simple:

```
.ModalWindow {border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;background:#f0f0f0;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;width: 800px;height: 500px;}
```

It seems strange but do I have to add a `display:none` to the CSS? Or is there another way to get them to be invisible in IE10?

EDIT: I will add that it works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

EDIT 2: After some digging I have found I'm getting two errors:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of 
     undefined or null reference 
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be 
     null for Controls and Behaviors.
```

I've never seen these errors before.

Comment: This kind of crap is why I left WebForms +MS AJAX behind in favor of MVC + plain JS/JQuery. Way easier than spelunking this type of conflict.

Comment: An absolute pain. IE10 is just ridiculous as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to this problem.

[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) you can find the bug fix for ASP.Net.

The header for the article in question is: **Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position**

Which is the underlying problem of the error messages I was receiving.