# Modal popup always visible?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am using asp.net and iis 7.5. I have upgraded server from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 and upgraded .net framework from 4 o 4.5.1. First think I have notices when fired up a website on a new server is that all ModalPopupExtenders are always visible by default.

Tried to find a solution and discovered there is a hotfix for this issue using this post [IE10 and Modal Popup Extender always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943073/ie10-and-modal-popup-extender-always-visible)

Unfortunately when I wanted to install it, I received an error message it is not possible to install this hotfix on current system.

Is there an other way to resolve this issue? I tested it on IE10 and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a javascipt error "unable to get property ui of undefined or null reference". The answer is that instead of asp:ScriptManager you need to use ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager in order for Ajax controls to be rendered in a proper way.